# Randomly Delete Columns From Datasets

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a dataset with the following format:

```
id = 1:1000
var1 = rexp(1000,1000)
var2 = rexp(1000,1000)
var3 = rexp(1000,1000)
var4 = rexp(1000,1000)
var5 = rexp(1000,1000)
var6 = rexp(1000,1000)
var7 = rexp(1000,1000)
var8 = rexp(1000,1000)
var9 = rexp(1000,1000)
var10 = rexp(1000,1000)

problem_data = data.frame(id, var1, var2, var3, var4,var5, var6, var7, var8, var9, var10)
```

From var1 to var10, I want to randomly delete 3 columns - here is my attempt:

```
rand =  sample(2:11, 3)
[1] 10 11  6

problem_data = problem_data[, -c(rand)]
```

I think I have done this correctly - but Ideally I would like to hear some comments. Have I done this correctly?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes you did correctly

Comment: Correct. You don't need `c` here: `problem_data = problem_data[, -rand]`.